# why do we consider xml when we named the AJAX?

Tags: ajax

I have been working with AJAX lot of time. In those instance, I have used json, plain html and xml to send the server response to client side. My question is why AJAX stand for asynchronous xml? we can use other format also to send the server response as I mentioned earlier.

This may be silly question but anybody know why does AJAX name come from asynchronous xml?

Comment: It's historical, XML was the original data notation used with it. See the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming) this part in particular XMLHttpRequest

Comment: AJAX is based on the JavaScript XMLHttpRequest object – and that was likely named by it’s inventors because that was the primary purpose they had in mind when creating it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)#History

Answer (score 2):

At the core of it, you're using an `XMLHttpRequest` object, that is part of the native Javascript library.